# Installing node 10.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, redhat

I ran the below to install nodejs 10.x and got the below error.

wget -qO- https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -

Installing the NodeSource Node.js 10.x repo...
Inspecting system...
rpm -q --whatprovides redhat-release || rpm -q --whatprovides centos-release || rpm -q --whatprovides cloudlinux-release || rpm -q --whatprovides sl-release
uname -m

Confirming "el6-x86_64" is supported...
curl -sLf -o /dev/null 'https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_10.x/el/6/x86_64/nodesource-release-el6-1.noarch.rpm'

Your distribution, identified as "redhat-release-server-6Server-6.7.0.3.0.1.el6.x86_64", is not currently supported, please contact NodeSource at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues if you think this is incorrect or would like your distribution to be considered for support
Could you please help to fix this?

Thanks!